# Why do we use normal approximation for sample proportions of cases involving a binomial distribution?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I'm in high school and am learning sample proportions. I have encountered a doubt that i cannot answer myself.

Why do we use normal **approximation** for sample proportions of cases involving a binomial distribution?

Why approximate? We have a binomial distribution, isn't it more accurate to just use this?

For example,

A company employs a sales team of 20 people, consisting of 12 men and 8 women. 5 sales people are to be selected at random to attend an important conference. Determine the probability that the proportion of men, in a random sample of 5 selected from the sales team, is greater than 0.7.

To solve this question, my teachers would say use normal distribution with $X$ being $N \sim (3, 0.048)$ to calculate the probabilty of $(X>0.7)$ in my calculator.

My problem here is: wouldn't it make more sense to calculate using binomial distribution with $X$ being $Bin \sim (5,0.6)$ then, as $0.7\times 5$ is $3.5$ round down to $3$ as you can't have $3.5$ men, calculating probability of $(X>3)$ in my calculator.

Can someone please clarify this? :D

Thanks

Comment: With bigger numbers it becomes more annoying to calculate with the binomial distribution. For example, suppose you wanted to estimate the probability that if you flipped $1000$ fair coins you get somewhere between $470$ and $530$ heads. To calculate this directly would involve summing $61$ large binomial coefficients. But estimating it with the normal distribution is comparatively easy.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan "easy" if you have a computer, because as far as I know the normal probabilities cannot be calculated by hand :) But I agree that, computationally, normal probabilities seems faster to calculate than binomial ones, at least for large n

Comment: @QiaochuYuan - So this approximation is simply to fix the practical problem of evaluating the answer by binomial? Which means when i my teacher took marks off for using binomial instead of normal i wasn't actually wrong? I'm going to mention this to my teacher hehe :D Thanks guys!

Comment: It depends on the context. If it was clear from context that you were supposed to use a normal approximation then that would be a different story. It’s also worth noting that this isn’t actually a binomial distribution either, since we’re sampling the sales team without replacement.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, the normal approximation is inappropriate for this problem because the sample size is simply too small, although, through sheer luck, it does happen to give a fairly good approximation to the exact probability, provided you choose the right variate value (namely $3.5$) to plug into it.

The exact probability that your random sample of $\ 5\ $ contains $\ m\ $ men and $\ 5-m\ $ women is
$$
p_m=\frac{{12\choose m}{8\choose5-m}}{20\choose5}\ .
$$
The first factor in the numerator of this fraction is the number of ways of choosing $\ m\ $ men from the $12$ available, the second factor is the number of ways of choosing $\ 5-m\ $ women from the $8$ available, and the denominator is the total number of ways of choosing
$5$ people from the $20$ available.  For the proportion of men in your sample of $\ 5\ $ to be greater than $\ 0.7\ $, $\ m\ $ must be $4$ or $5$, and the probability of this occurring is
$$
\frac{{12\choose4}{8\choose1}+{12\choose5}}{20\choose5}=\frac{99}{323}\approx0.3065\ .
$$
The binomial approximation, on the other hand, gives an estimate of
$$
{5\choose4}\times0.6^4\times0.4+{5\choose5}\times0.6^5\approx 0.337\ ,
$$
which is about $10\%$ too large.

The true standard deviation of the number of men in the sample is $\ \displaystyle\sqrt{\sum_{m=0}^5p_m(i-3)^2}\approx0.973\ $, while that of the approximating binomial distribution is $\ \sqrt{5\times0.6\times0.4}\approx1.095\ $, again about $10\%$ too large.  If $\ X\ $ is a normally-distributed random variable with mean $3$ and standard deviation $0.973$, then $\ P(X>0.7\times5)\approx0.3037\ $, which is a pretty good approximation to the exact probability.  However, $\ P(X>3)=0.5\ $ and $\ P(X\ge4)\approx0.152\ $, both very poor approximations.  Given that these three probabilities should be equal for an integer valued random variable, it becomes apparent that the closeness of $\ P(X>0.7\times5)\ $ to the exact probability is largely a matter of luck that the fraction chosen in the problem happened to have been  $0.7$ rather than some other fraction in the range $0.6$ to $0.8$.